# Rdius packets whith Acct_Status_Type = 2 and no Framed IP address

Tags: radius

While working with RADIUS packets, I found that packets with:

```
Acct-Status-Type: Stop (2)
```

And:

```
radius.Acct_Terminate_Cause == 17 (User_Error)
```

Do not have the framed IP address and MASK of the client   (I mean AVPs):

```
AVP: l=6 t=Framed-IP-Address(8):  AND 
AVP: l=6 t=Framed-IP-Netmask(9):
```

I want to know if this is always the case, and if it is "normal behavior".

I looked in the RFC but did not find a response.

Answer (score 0):

finally, i found that those packets are sent when a non allowed subscriber tries to connect.

There are many cases where a subscriber is not allowed to connect, one of them is if his password is not correct.

accourding to RADIUS RFC2866, Acct-Terminate-Cause has 18 possible values:

```
  1       User Request
  2       Lost Carrier
  3       Lost Service
  4       Idle Timeout
  5       Session Timeout
  6       Admin Reset
  7       Admin Reboot
  8       Port Error
  9       NAS Error
  10      NAS Request
  11      NAS Reboot
  12      Port Unneeded
  13      Port Preempted
  14      Port Suspended
  15      Service Unavailable
  16      Callback
  17      User Error
  18      Host Request
```

Best Regards.